# TypeError: unbound method make_request() must be called with XX instance, but how?

Tags: python

Running the code below I get

E       TypeError: unbound method make_request() must be called with A instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

I dont want to set make_request method as static, I want to call it from an instance of an object.

The example   http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-function

```
# content of ./test_smtpsimple.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def smtp():
    import smtplib
    return smtplib.SMTP("merlinux.eu")

def test_ehlo(smtp):
    response, msg = smtp.ehlo()
    assert response == 250
    assert "merlinux" in msg
    assert 0 # for demo purposes
```

My code

```
""" """
import pytest


class  A(object):
    """  """
    def __init__(self, name ):
        """ """
        self._prop1 = [name]


    @property
    def prop1(self):
        return self._prop1  

    @prop1.setter
    def prop1(self, arguments):
        self._prop1 = arguments

    def make_request(self, sex):
        return 'result'

    def __call__(self):
        return self


@pytest.fixture()
def myfixture():
    """ """
    A('BigDave')
    return A

def test_validateA(myfixture):
    result = myfixture.make_request('male')
    assert result =='result'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try replacing your last two methods as: -

```
@pytest.fixture()
def myfixture():
    """ """
    return A('BigDave')

def test_validateA(myfixture):
    result = myfixture().make_request('male')
    assert result =='result'
```

`myfixture` is the function object. To invoke the function you need a bracket on it. So, `myfixture()`.

Now in `myfixture()` method, `return A` again returns the class object. In order to return an `instance` of class A, on which you will call your method, you need to return either `A()` or just return the `A('BigDave')` you are using there.

So, now your `test_validateA` method will get an instance of class `A` from `myfixture` method, on which you are invoking the method, thus passing the `self` as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

@pytest.fixture()   creates a instance of the fixture object

@pytest.fixture accesses the fixture class directly.

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
    """ """
    A('BigDave')
    return A
```

vs

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
    """ """

    return  A('BigDave')
```